# Errors in Affine and Perspective Transformations During Image Registration

Tags: python, image-processing, sift, affinetransform, image-registration

I’m currently working on an image registration algorithm to register aerial imagery by means of deep learning techniques.
Due to my lack of experience with Affine and Perspective Transformations I'm unable to debug the following:

[image: Transformations]

The image on the left is an Affine Transform of the data while the image on the right is a perspective transform of the same data.

During execution the algorithm starts out just fine but suffers from image misalignment (*Repeated Features*) in the case of Affine Transformations and an occurrence of *Stretched Corners* in case of Perspective Transformations.

These errors are persistent despite filtering outliers using RANSAC and using the very best of matches. Regardless of using Deep Learning Techniques or SIFT for image feature extraction the error is still persistent

My goal is to maintain the same accuracy with image registration throughout execution. I assume the error is due to *Accumulated Error in Homography* and can be rectified through *Homography Optimization*.

Please Advise.

The source code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/ArunLukeDsouza/Orthomapping-with-Deep-Learning-on-Aerial-Imagery).

Comment: projective transforms may be unsuited for this task. Errors accumulate since a single mis-registration that leads to a large warp will then force all of the following images to also be very warped. I don't use affine transformations much, but I suspect similar compounding errors could show up there as well. How do the results look if you restrict yourself to translation and rotation? This could also make it easier to train a network since you know it'll always be matching on un-warped images. If possible, can you post this sequence of images so that we can experiment?

Comment: Sure, I'm working with the Crop Field (RGB) dataset which can be downloaded [here](https://www.sensefly.com/dataset/crops-field-dataset-rgb-ebee-sq/)